# find specific row in table with soup.find_all pythonm

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, findall

I want to get the specific string from a table, so:

```
soup.findAll("td", {"class": "spec-value"})
```

the result is:

```
All In One                            </td>, <td class="spec-value">
Asus                            </td>, <td class="spec-value">
All in one Z272SDT                            </td>, <td class="spec-value">
27''                            </td>, <td class="spec-value">
UHD 3840X2160                            </td>, <td class="spec-value">
```

but i want to get only the 3rd string (All in one Z272SDT)

how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
soup.findAll("td", {"class": "spec-value"})[2].text
```

Comment: your'e the best :)